# Google Charts adding rows from array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, google-visualization

I have been struggling with Google charts for a few days now and have decided to ask for some help, hopefully this will be clear.
I have a PHP app I have inherited and I am trying to update the chart visual reporting side of things.

I'm converting the PHP array to json via:

```
var passedArray =  <?php echo json_encode($values_fixed); ?>;
```

This is working as per my tests, for this example im getting values 40,50. Some real world versions will have more than 2 values.
The code I am using to iterate through the array is as follows:

```
    for (var a = 0; a < passedArray.length; a++) {
         data.addRow([passedArray[a].anything , null ]);
    }
```

The issue I am having is the above code will display a chart, but there is no data, its just blank. It is iterating using the above as I can force some values in there and it will display them 2 times (array length is 2). Im pretty sure the issue is passedArray[a].anything - however if I remove the .anything the chart will break and not display at all. So changing this to:

```
    for (var a = 0; a < passedArray.length; a++) {
         data.addRow([passedArray[a], null ]);
    }
```

above will just prevent the chart from displaying at all, it completely breaks the code and no chart, not even a blank one will display.
What am I doing wrong here? How do I get the code to iterate through the array adding a new value to a row dynamically?

Full code below, I had to rip a whole bunch of testing bits and pieces out of here so hopefully ive not  missed anything...

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    var passedArray =  <?php echo json_encode($values_fixed); ?>; 
    
      // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
            
            for (var a = 0; a < passedArray.length; a++) {
                 data.addRow([null, passedArray[a].anything]);
            }

        
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
    

</head>
<body>
    
    <p id="demo"></p>
      <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart"></div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Try moving the script element, the one with the chart handling and the contents, to _just before_ the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: pie chart requires a string and a number. it appears you are passing a string with `anything`, but `null` as the number. where is the pie slice value? that is why a blank chart is drawn, there are no values -- will you please share a sample of the data? --> `<?php echo json_encode($values_fixed); ?>`

Comment: Thanks whitehat, I can see I have put it that way round in the code excerpt, its the other way round in the full code example and still does not work. I think the crux of it is that i need to have passedArray[a].anything in there or the chart will not display at all. So the code can read passedArray[a].hjkhk and the chart will render (all be it with no data) - if i change it to passedArray[a] then it breaks things and I dont get a blank chart to display - nothing renders. So im not sure why it requires this and if it does what the value should be.

Comment: The php array $values_fixed is a count of the number of hits for a value - in this case its a count of number of values for (male / female), for clients in a db. The values output by both the original php array is:
Array ( [0] => 40 [1] => 50 )